# SharePoint 2013 a different navigation menu for a subsite

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

Hello I have a problem with the top navigation.

I have created a sub-site from a site collection. now, the sub-site has a different master page that is similar to the master page in the site collection. the site has a navigation menu and when I create the sub-site it inherits it's top navigation menu. Now I want a different navigation menu and I don't know how to configure it. when I create the current navigation for the sub-site it still showing me the navigation from the top site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay Finally found a solution:

this is how the navigation bar looks inside the master page:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource
            ShowStartingNode="False"
            SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider"
            id="topSiteMap"
            runat="server"
            StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002"/>
    <SharePoint:AspMenu
        ID="TopNavigationMenu"
        Runat="server"
        CssClass ="mega-menu"
        EnableViewState="false"
        DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
        AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
        UseSimpleRendering="true"
        UseSeparateCss="false"
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        StaticDisplayLevels="2"
        AdjustForShowStartingNode="false"
        MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"
        SkipLinkText=""

        />
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

all I needed was to change in the "SiteMapProvider" to value shown above.
hope it helps someone!